# Changing coordinates of given differential form

Tags: differential-forms, polar-coordinates

I've been given the following differential form:

$$\eta = -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$$

and need to express it in the polar coordinates $(x,y) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$. To do so I did the following calculation:

$$-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} = -\frac{r\sin\theta}{r^2} = -\frac{\sin\theta}{r}$$
$$\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{r\cos\theta}{r^2} =\frac{\cos\theta}{r}$$

and

$$dx = d(x(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)) = \frac{\partial(r\cos\theta)}{\partial r}dr+\frac{\partial(r\cos\theta)}{\partial \theta}d\theta = \cos\theta dr -r\sin\theta d\theta$$
$$dy = d(y(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)) = \frac{\partial(r\sin\theta)}{\partial r}dr+\frac{\partial(r\sin\theta)}{\partial \theta}d\theta = \sin\theta dr +r\cos\theta d\theta$$

So the final answer should be
$$(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta) \,d\theta+\frac{(\sin\theta\cos\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta)}{r}\,dr= d\theta$$

---

Is this correct? More generally, if a form is
$$\omega = \omega_xdx + \omega_ydy$$
then does the application of some pullback $\Phi$ yield

$$\Phi^{*}\omega =(\omega_x\circ\Phi)(d\Phi^{*}x)+(\omega_y\circ\Phi)(d\Phi^{*}y)$$

always?

Comment: Yes, $d\theta$ is correct.